# Three.js r88 - memory leak

Tags: javascript, three.js

Forward: I've already looked at every three.js memory leak post I can find, and the majority of them are out dated with deprecated functions. Even the newer ones produce no results in this situation.

Client side frameworks: React v15.5.4, ThreeJS r88.

Here is a performance profile of the JS Heap:

[image]

Everything is working fine during the render loop. I would expect the blue JS Heap line to be at the bottom after I change components and trigger my cleanup function in the components componentWillUnmount lifecycle method. Unfortunately this is not the case. Where the blue line becomes flat is where the change in components takes place and the cleanup code is executed. Somehow the heap increases???

Here is the code that adds objects to the scene and the cleanup / disposal mechanisms:

```
/*
* This is how the models are added to the scene. A listener is added to each object in the scene
* to invoke Builder.prototype.model._dispose when the remove event is triggered
*/
//..
init: {
    // ...
    _modelInScene: function( modelData ) {
        const { dimensions, index, model, sectionModelsArray, tableConfig, type } = modelData;

        sectionModelsArray.push( model );

        // size and position model
        //Builder.model._sizeAndPosition( { model, dimensions, type, index }, tableConfig );

        // add model to scene
        _threejs.scene.add( model );

        model.addEventListener( "removed", Builder.prototype.model._dispose );

        // store type of model on model meshes so that we can get this information during raycasting
        model.traverse( function ( child ) {
            child.addEventListener( "removed", Builder.prototype.model._dispose );

            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                child._modelType = type;
            }
        } );
    },
    // ...
},
//..
/*
* This is the function triggered in componentWillUnmount method of the react component that contains
* the three js scene. In this function I remove all top level children from the scene. This triggers
* the listeners for the remove event and calls the dispose function which releases geometry, materials,
* and removes nested objects from scene triggering their remove events etc...
*/
//...
cleanup: function() {
    // dispose of scene listeners
    Builder.prototype._removeListeners();

    // TODO - implement cache

    // clear the model cache
    //Builder.prototype.model._clearCache();

    // clear the texture cache
    //Builder.prototype.texture._clearCache();

    // remove tableConfig from _threejs object
    _tableConfig = null;

    // reset tableConfig in redux store
    _dispatch( removeTable() );

    // remove all children from scene
    while( _threejs.scene.children.length > 0 ) {
        _threejs.scene.remove( _threejs.scene.children[ 0 ] );
    }

    // remove reference to animations in the heightAnimationController
    if ( _threejs.heightAnimationController ) _threejs.heightAnimationController.dispose();

    // reset _shouldCastRay to false
    _shouldCastRay = false;

    // dispose of controls listeners
    _threejs.controls.dispose();

    // dispose of rendering context
    _threejs.renderer.dispose();

    // reset _threejs object
    _threejs = {
        camera: null,
        controls: null,
        heightAnimationController: null,
        lookAt: null,
        mouseCoords: null,
        raycaster: null,
        raycasterTargetModels: [],
        renderer: null,
        scene: null,
        sceneHeight: 0,
        sceneWidth: 0,
        tableConfig: null
    };

    // cancel requestAnimationFrame from Builder.prototype._animate3js
    cancelAnimationFrame( _animationFrameId );
},
//...

/*
* Dispose function invoked by remove listeners
*/
//...
model: {
    //..
    _dispose: function() {
        const target = arguments[ 0 ].target;

        if ( target instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            if ( target.geometry ) {
                target.geometry.dispose();
            }

            if ( target.material ) {
                if ( target.material.bumpMap ) target.material.bumpMap.dispose();
                if ( target.material.envMap ) target.material.envMap.dispose();
                if ( target.material.lightMap ) target.material.lightMap.dispose();
                if ( target.material.map ) target.material.map.dispose();
                if ( target.material.normalMap ) target.material.normalMap.dispose();
                if ( target.material.specularMap ) target.material.specularMap.dispose();

                target.material.dispose();
            }
        } else {
            while ( target.children.length > 0 ) {
                target.remove( target.children[ 0 ] );
            }
        }
    },
    //..
},
//..
```

During cleanup I dispose of OrbitControls, WebGLRenderingContext, all Textures, and Geometries, and remove all references to anything three.js related.

Also, the react component that I'm changing to is just an empty div element. There is nothing in this stateless component that would explain the jump in the heap.

I've spent many hours looking through the three.js source, on stackoverflow, and on other sites trying to figure this one out. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The "models" that get added to the scene are instances of `THREE.Scene` and contain Object3D containers with Meshes in them. They are exported from blender and loaded via `THREE.ObjectLoader`. Just in case that is pertinent.

EDIT #2: After more research on finding and fixing memory leaks I have a better timeline to display. This has a forced garbage collection at the beginning and the heap is at 13,522,544. The large spike is the initialization of the three js scene and the loading of the models. That part is expected. After leaving the three js portion of the app, running the disposal code, and then forcing another garbage collection. After the second garbage collection I would expect the heap to be the same as at the beginning. I am in the same place int he app and all of three js should have been cleaned up, but the heap is now 14,830,808; an increase of 1,308,264.

Here is the timeline:

[image]

I can provide any requested information, currently spinning wheels :(

EDIT #3:

I've reduced the leak to approximately 100kb per initialization and deconstruction of models. Unfortunately the comparison between snapshots is in my mind, rather vague. (I am new to fixing leaks though!)

[image]

It looks like everything makes it way back to THREE or webpackJsonp. Any advice on this? I think this might be something I just have to live with if I want to use the libraries.

Comment: In Chrome, you can take two heap snapshots and compare them for deltas. It might be worthwhile to perform one dump after your initial forced garbage collection, and another after the second forced garbage collection. You can then filter on "THREE" to see if any THREE-specific objects are hanging out. It'll be harder to tell if the objects are, say `Float32Array`s (as used by buffers), especially if the original parent object is gone.

Comment: @TheJim01added an update.

Comment: 100kb per model isn't much, unless you're loading thousands of models. (I know, as a programmer, you want memory to start at `0` and return to `0`, but JavaScript is far from a perfect world). What you're showing in your screenshot is only the delta of plain JavaScript arrays. If that's where most of your memory is being swallowed, then you might be out of luck unless you want to check every one to see if it's something you can handle better to allow those arrays to get garbage collected.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by coming at the problem from an architectural stand point. Instead of trying to break down the whole three js environment, I leave the environment alone and just add remove and objects and dispose of textures and geometries as needed. The leak had to do with disposing of the renderer and creating a new one. I'm going to leave this question open in case some three js god sees it and can explain to me what I was doing wrong with the renderer, or if it is a three js optimization issue.

Comment: Were you giving it a canvas to use each time, or were you utilizing the `renderer.domElement` it generates?

Comment: I was using the renderer.domElement - Oddly THREE was retaining nested references to things in the renderer even after the dispose though. Even with renderer.dispose(), controls.dispose(), and recursive disposal of all textures, texture maps, and geometries in the scene; the renderer still had cached references to textures.